# Basic Authentication for Axis2 throught Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, apache-axis, basic-authentication

I'm trying to add Basic Authentication for my web-service based on Axis2.
Tomcat successfully pass auth data to web-service code but weblogic uses this information for its purposes (tries to authenticate the request).
Is it possible to configure weblogic to allow passing auth data depends on URL for example?

Comment: Can you give more information? It's hard to tell what your question means or what your goal is. Have you looked at weblogic authentication tutorials like: http://instantkick.blogspot.com/2013/03/How-to-Implement-Weblogic-Basic-Authentication.html

Comment: I have Axis web service. Inside it there is a code that parse "Basic Auth" credentials and verify them. If I'm deploying my web-service to Tomcat and sending the request to it with user/password "Basic Auth" credentials everything works fine. WS code pars user/pass successfully. But when I deploy my WS to weblogic after the request I'm getting 401 because my user/pass become applied to WL authentication system and they are not delivered to my WS. How can I reconfigure my WS/WL to allow "Basic Auth" credentials become proxified directly to WS, and restrict WL to touch them.